# Can't parse a json (String) using HandyJSON. Error (Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'HandyJSON')

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I started to study IOS and I have a question.
I'm trying to get Json (String) using HandyJSON, but I get an error and do not understand what I need to do, please tell me. Using  X-Code 10

```
func updateMedicalHelpStatus(username: String, password: String, access_token: String, status: Int) {
        AF.request(MainApi.feedsListBegin, parameters: ParametersApi.parametersTokenStatus(access_token: access_token, status: status), encoding:
            URLEncoding.default, headers: HTTPHeadersApi.headersLoginPassword(username: username, password: password)).responseJSON {
                response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    do {
                        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: response.result.value, options: .prettyPrinted)
                        let reqJSONStr = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
                        let jsonResponse = BaseResponse<String>.deserialize(from: reqJSONStr)

                        if jsonResponse?.success == true  {
                                self.view.updateMedicalHelpStatusSuccessfully()
                        } else{
                                self.view.error(message: "")
                        }
                    }
                    catch {
                        self.view.error(message: "\(error)")
                    }
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    self.view.error(message: "\(error)")
                }
        }
    }

import Foundation
import HandyJSON
class BaseResponse<T: HandyJSON>: BaseError{
    let success: Bool = false
    let body: T? = nil
    required init() {      
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you are new to swift I would recommend to stick with Swift's own framework’s as much as possible before using 3rd party frameworks. This is specially true for json since the built in support, using Codable, is very good and widely used so it is much easier to find information and get answers to your questions

Comment: Yes, I tried to use Codable, but I can not start with Codable and use it.

Comment: I decided this problem use cotable.